# Set property to null from outside of the instance

Tags: c#, .net

I have identified the following behavior which I'm having a hard time understanding.

I was assuming that you could set the property of an Object A to an Object B, manipulate the Object B and that the changes would be carried on to the property of Object A (because it is the same object). I was expecting this unit test to pass but it fails at the last line when setting B to null. Why?

```
    [TestMethod]
    public void TestObject()
    {
        Child child = new Child();
        var parent = new Parent(child);
        child.Name = "John";
        Assert.AreEqual(parent.Child.Name, "John");
        child = null;
        Assert.IsNull(parent.Child);
    }

    public class Child
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }   
    }

    public class Parent
    {
        public Child Child { get; set; }

        public Parent(Child kid)
        {
            Child = kid;
        }
    }
```

Comment: "crashes" doesn't really tell us anything.  Exceptions are much more useful.

Comment: Setting `child` to null is only setting the local variable `child`. `parent.Child` still points to the instance that was assigned to `child` when `parent` was constructed.

Comment: Indeed child is set to null but not parent.child. If you were to set parent.child to null it would work the way you intend.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

This line

```
child = null;
```

is not doing what you think it does. It nulls out the reference to the `Child` object that your `TestObject()` method holds, but it has no effect on the reference to the same `Child` object held by the `Parent` object:

Before you assign `child = null`:

[image: Before the change]

After you assign `child = null`:

[image: After the change]

That is why

```
Assert.IsNull(parent.Child);
```

fails: `parent.Child` reference is different from `child` reference that you have nulled out.

On the other hand, if you do `child.Name = null` then `parent.Child.Name` would become `null` as well:

```
child.Name = null;
Assert.IsNull(parent.Child.Name);
```

Comment: I assume that the GC will only collect the Child object once the Parent object is destroyed in this scenario?

Comment: @Keysharpener Absolutely! GC would not collect an object until the last reachable reference to it is gone. If you set `parent` to `null`, the reference `parent.Child` would become unreachable, so both `Parent` and `Child` would become eligible for GC.

Answer (score 5):

You are making a mistake around how references work. When you pass in the `Child` object to the `Parent` object you are passing a reference to that object. That means when you change the name on the `Child` object it is the `Parent.child` sees those changes because it is a reference to the same object.  For the time, your `child` variable and `Parent.child` property point to the same reference, that's why setting name changes it in the way you expect. However, when you set `child` to null you are changing it's reference, it now points to no object (null), but you haven't done anything to manipulate the reference that `Parent.child` is pointing to, it still has a reference to the original object, so it is not changed to null because all you have done in setting `child = null` is remove the reference to the object, not changed the object in any way.  It is the same as if you have

```
Child child2 = child;
child = null;
```

`child2` in this case won't be set to `null`, because the object `child2` is pointing to is the original `child` reference and all you have done is remove that use of the reference, not manipulated the reference at all yourself.

Answer (score 3):

The Child property is a reference to the actual Child object in memory.  Your local variable "child" is another different reference to the same object.  When you set your local child to null, it doesn't touch your Parent's reference to it.
If you set the Name property on either reference, that is changing the actual object and you will see it reflected thru both references to it.